# How to filter search results in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, web

I'm new to PHP and Laravel, and I'm working on a project where people will be able to enter information about certain products and services available in different locations. I've added search functionality to enable users to search the database for specific products, but I want to take if further. When users search for products and the results are displayed, I want them to be able to filter the results to see the products and services available in their specific location.

**Model**

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Khaki extends Model {
    public function scopeSearch($query, $s) {
        return $query->where('what_size_do_you_want', 'like', '%' . $s . '%')->orWhere('camp_sites', 'like', '%' . $s . '%');
    }
}
```

**Controller**

```
public function index(Request  $request) {
    $s = $request->input('s');
    $khaki = Khaki::latest()->search($s)->paginate(10);
    return view('khaki.index', compact('khaki', 's'));
}
```

Comment: So you're talking about front-end filtering of the data, right? You're going to need to use a plugin like Datatables, or roll your own JS logic for filtering/searching. Alternatively, you use HTML to GET/POST the request with additional variables for filtering, searching, sorting, etc. Regardless, unless you've tried something and found an issue, this is way too broad.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use `DataTable` its makes you life easy see [docs](https://datatables.net/).

> See this [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mrf2Ljef/3/)

Comment: But it fitlers the results in view, wich means you are still pulling out all the results with no filters. we need something to filter while pulling

Comment: DataTable also offer [Column filtering](https://datatables.net/extensions/fixedheader/examples/options/columnFiltering.html)